# OnActivated during constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-embedded

When *during* the constructor of a `Form` I touch specific properties (ie. the `Width` property), it immediately invokes `OnActivated()`. I only notice this behavior on my device running Windows Embedded 7 and the .NET 3.5 that comes with it.

Here's the code I use to reproduce the issue:

```
static class Program
{
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        new MyForm();
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        Width = 100;
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Activated!");
    }
}
```

(Notice that I'm not `Show()`ing the form nor using `Application.Run()`)

Running the above code on my desktop or WinCE 5 device does not show the `MessageBox`. On my Windows Embedded 7 device, the `MessageBox` appears, and after clicking "OK" it re-appears because `OnActivated()` is being invoked again.

The device manufacturer told me this is an OS specific issue, can anyone confirm that this is how Windows Embedded 7 should "treat his forms"?

Comment: (If this question seems familiar, I posted this question before, but removed it allowing the manufacturer to investigate first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this on my Windows CE 5.0 device with .NET CF 3.5 to see if I experienced the same behavior as you. With the exact same code, I did not have OnActivated get called. Setting the Width did not cause OnActivated to be called even when Application.Run() was used instead. In fact, it appeared that the Form had to have been shown to allow Activate to fire because I tried calling Activate() explicitly.

So it appears to be something that Windows Embedded 7 does versus previous versions of Windows CE. I also tried to look into the CompactFramework .NET .dlls using Reflector, but I did not find any code in .NET that would Activate a Form when its width was changed. The Width is not a property of Form (it is a property of Control), and Form did not appear to handle the resize event in anyway that would allow it to call its Activate method.

I do have a suggestion for you as a possible workaround. The following code prevented Activate  from occuring completely even when I explicitly called Activate();

Give this a try:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisableActivate();
        Activate(); // No call is made to OnActivated
        EnableActivate();
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Activated");
    }

    private void DisableActivate()
    {
        WindowStyles style = GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EX_STYLE);
        style |= WindowStyles.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EX_STYLE, style);
    }

    private void EnableActivate()
    {
        WindowStyles style = GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EX_STYLE);
        style &= ~WindowStyles.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
        SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EX_STYLE, style);
    }

    public const int GWL_EX_STYLE = -20;

    [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern WindowStyles GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("Coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, WindowStyles dwNewLong);

    [Flags]
    public enum WindowStyles : uint
    {
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
        WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000,
        WS_GROUP = 0x00020000,
        WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000,
        WS_OVERLAPPED = WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION,
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x04000000,
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000,
        WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000,    /* WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME  */
        WS_BORDER = 0x00800000,
        WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000,
        WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000,
        WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000,
        WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000,
        WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000,
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000,
        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000,
        WS_SIZEBOX = WS_THICKFRAME,
        WS_POPUP = 0x80000000,
        WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000,
        WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x00000001,
        WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008,
        WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080,
        WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE = 0x00000100,
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200,
        WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP = 0x00000400,
        WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x00001000,
        WS_EX_RTLREADING = 0x00002000,
        WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR = 0x00004000,
        WS_EX_STATICEDGE = 0x00020000,
        WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = 0x00100000, // Disable inheritence of mirroring by children
        WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x00400000, // Right to left mirroring
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = (WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE),
        WS_EX_CAPTIONOKBTN = 0x80000000,
        WS_EX_NODRAG = 0x40000000,
        WS_EX_ABOVESTARTUP = 0x20000000,
        WS_EX_INK = 0x10000000,
        WS_EX_NOANIMATION = 0x04000000
    }
}
```

So basically, with your code do:

```
public MyForm()
{
    DisableActivate();
    Width = 100;
    EnableActivate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try your solution tomorrow (the device is at the office). Still curious whether this is a platform issue or truly what Windows Embedded 7 is designed to do, if the `Activate`/`Deactivate` still occur "in sync", you may just have saved me alot of digging in old code :)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Also, I'm not sure what is bad about having OnActivate get called, but if you are executing code in OnActivate that you only want to happen once, you can just set a boolean at the end of the constructor. Only execute the code from OnActivate if the boolean is set (meaning the constructor is complete). Actually, you could just check IsVisible or some other property as an additional condition to execute that code. If you do need to suppress activate completely, then try my answer's code.

Comment: the problem is we have legacy code which needs to be ported to this platform, and accesses resources in `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` that are initialized in the constructor. It's tested code and I'd rather have a solid workaround in one place than a rewrite of the existing code. Going to try work with your information now.

Comment: This works great! The `OnActivated` that would trigger _during_ the constructor is now even invoked after `OnLoad`. I can place `DisableActivate()` in the constructor and `EnableActivate()` in the `OnLoad` of a base class, and fix this for every form. Thank you!!

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I'm glad I was able to help!