# Upgrade c# application from windows CE 5 to embedded compact 7

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I've inherited an embedded application for a scanner, it was written using visual studio 2005, C#.  We now have to replace the hardware because we can't get the old ones anymore.  Unfortunately, the replacement device runs on embedded compact 7.0.  I've rebuilt the application and installed it on the new device.  It runs but we do get some strange behaviour.  Is embedded compact 7 fully compatible with ce 5?  How would I go about upgrading it to ec 7.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can specify "strange behaviour"? In general the app should work without issues. But this depends on the code.

Comment: I think I might've found the issue, it wasn't deploying correctly and was missing a dll.

Comment: That results normally not in strange behaviour but an exception.

Comment: No, there was no exception being thrown.  The offending method call is to a third party dll which seems to execute as normal.  But once we were able to debug it, we saw a message in the output window saying method not found.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21932099/292411) because we had issues migrating our application from WindowsCE 5 to Windows Embedded Compact 7:

If you are using `Form`s, on WindowsCE 5 the constructor will always complete before `OnActivated` would be called, while on Embedded Compact 7, when you adjust certain `Form` properties, `OnActivated` would be called *before* the constructor would finish. This also applies to `OnGotFocus` and perhaps `OnLoad`, and their events (ie. `form1_Activated`).

Now no one has confirmed nor denied this behavior on their devices, so I'm not completely sure if this is a vendor-specific problem. You can run the code in the question to determine whether this also happens on your device.

Aside from that (and a larger screen, so we had to redesign the user interface :P) we've not had any issues migrating.